# Print Entire Row When Second and Third Columns Match Numeric Pattern

Tags: csv, unix, awk, grep

I need to print the entire row when the 2nd and 3rd columns of a CSV match two floating point values, i.e. `36.*,-125.*`.

**Sample CSV (col2):**

```
54.43,36.01,-125.54
60.32,45.32,-86.21
32.67,20.55,-30.78
76.56,36.78,-125.98
```

**Attempted Code:**

```
cat col2 | awk -F',' '{print $2,$3}' |  grep -E '36.*,-125.*'
```

**Expected Result:**

```
54,36.01,-125.54
76,36.78,-125.98
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `Awk` as below (GNU Awk variant)

```
awk -vFS=, -vOFS=, '$2 ~ /^36\./ && $3 ~ /^[-]125\./' file
```

The part `-vFS=, -vOFS=,` sets you the input and output de-limiters as `,` which lets you parse the individual columns from `$1` to `$NF`. The regex match  condition `$2 ~ /^36\./` matches the records starting with `36.` and similarly for `$3` match the `-` with a bracket expression `[-]` (optional, could be used without it as `$3 ~ /^-125\./` also) to mark starting with `-125.` string.

The POSIX compliant version could be written with a space after `-v` and `FS=,` as `-v FS=,` or put it all together in the `BEGIN` clause

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2 ~ /^36\./ && $3 ~ /^[-]125\./' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go in this way instead of regex matching:

```
awk -F',' '$2>=36 && $2<37 && $3>-126 && $3<=-125' file
```

With this line, you don't have to care about if the `$2` with or without the `dot`, for example, `36 or 36.01`.

You gave your codes like: `36.*`, from there I think `36` should be in output too.

IMO, for this kind of job, the arithmetic comparison is always over regex, even if sometimes regex matching *can* do the job too.

Comment: shorter with `int($2)==36 && int($3)==-125`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed

```
sed -E 'h;s/[^,]*,(36)\.[^,]*,(-125)\..*$/\1\2/;tA;d;:A;x' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E "^[^,]*,36.[0-9]*,-125.[0-9]*" col2
```